# babel-jest: Babel ignores app/utils/myfile.js - make sure to include the file in Jest's transformIgnorePatterns as well

Tags: node.js, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I cannot get my jest tests to run when I have ignored a file with babel:

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  ignore: ['./app/utils/myfile.js'],
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: '14',
        },
        useBuiltIns: 'entry',
        corejs: '3.8',
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  setupFiles: ['./jest.init.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx)$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['myfile'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
};
```

i have added myfile.js to the babel ignore and to the jest transformIgnorePatterns. what could it be?